# sort-object and using the unique switch

Tags: powershell

I have an array of objects that look like

```
roleAssignmentId : 9176352783597733
roleId           : 9176352783597583
role             : _LEGACY_ENTERPRISE_SUPPORT_ROLE
assignedTo       : 108017007332853866995
assignedToUser   : purespace@domain.con
scopeType        : CUSTOMER
orgUnitId        :
orgUnit          :
```

I want to sort on `assignedToUser` and remove the duplicate objects.

If the array is `$i` and `$i | Sort-Object -Property $_.assignedToUser -Unique`
`$1` reduces down to 1 object.

There should be a way to sort the array on one property of the objects in the array and keep unique values.

I have tried

```
 $i  | Sort-Object -Property $_.assignedToUser -Unique
 $i  | Sort-Object -Property $_.assignedToUser -Unique[$_.assignedToUser]
 $i  | Sort-Object -Unique[$_.assignedToUser]
 $i  | Sort-Object -Unique
```

Comment: you need to pass in a scriptblock. `Sort-Object -Property { $_.assignedToUser } -Unique` or just refer to the property name and not use a expression, `Sort-Object -Property assignedToUser -Unique`